# Asp.net web application and windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET web application written in C# which is running fine in Visual Studio Pro.

When I publish it to IIS and click on the create computer account button, I am getting an error

> A constraint violation occurred

Looking for your support

Here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Text;

namespace UCSD
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void btnCreateComputerAccounts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ouName = "computers"; // Provide the OU name here
            string domainName = "ma.lan"; // Provide the domain name here

            List<string> results = new List<string>(); // Create a list to store the results

            using (DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{domainName}"))
            {
                // Split the computer accounts by newline and create a computer account for each one
                string[] computerAccounts = txtComputerAccounts.Text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                foreach (string computerAccount in computerAccounts)
                {
                    // Check if the computerAccount starts with "MA91M"
                    if (!computerAccount.StartsWith("MA91M"))
                    {
                        // Add a message to the results indicating that the computer account was skipped
                        results.Add($"Computer account '{computerAccount}' skipped because it does not start with 'MA91M'.");
                        continue; // Skip creating the computer account
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        using (DirectoryEntry computerEntry = directoryEntry.Children.Add($"CN={computerAccount}", "computer"))
                        {
                            string networkid = Environment.UserName.ToString();
                            computerEntry.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = computerAccount;
                            computerEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = 0x1000; // Enable the account
                            computerEntry.Properties["description"].Value = $"Account created by: {networkid}";
                            computerEntry.CommitChanges();
                        }

                        // Add the success message to the list
                        results.Add($"Computer account '{computerAccount}' created successfully.");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // Add the error message to the list
                        results.Add($"Failed to create computer account '{computerAccount}': {ex.Message}");
                    }
                }

                // Create a StringBuilder to store the HTML content
                StringBuilder htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                htmlBuilder.Append("<ul>");

                foreach (string result in results)
                {
                    htmlBuilder.Append($"<li>{result}</li>");
                }

                htmlBuilder.Append("</ul>");

                // Set the HTML content as the innerHTML of a div element with id "resultDiv"
                resultDiv.InnerHtml = htmlBuilder.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I enabled Windows authentication in IIS, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Which line throws that exception? Does the account accessing the directly have permission to do so?

Comment: This line “ results.Add($"Failed to create computer account '{computerAccount}': {ex.Message}");”  for the account I am using admin account

Comment: One of your properties is violating the AD rules. First thing to try is to comment out the properties one at a time to see which one is in violation. Use your debugger! Also, try checking the InnerException.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. When I ran the code in IIS Express, the code works fine. However, in normal IIS, it does not work."